# Get package sources and repository link

Tags: package-management, apt, dpkg

Is there any way (dpkg, apt?) to get a package's sources and URL to repository, if available, in Debian ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `sudo apt-get source packageName`? It installs the newest available source tree, when available, in the current working directory.

Check `man apt-get` for more details.

Comment: I need just the name. Is there a way to get it ? Also, how could I get the git repo URL from where it downloads the package ?

Comment: No real need for `sudo` here, right?

Answer (score 20):

for latest version:

```
apt-get download --print-uris package | cut -d' ' -f1
```

for specific version

```
apt-get download --print-uris package=version | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: kept trying this, but no path was printed. Found that having already downloaded the file with `apt-get download pkg` it will not print anything. So deleting the file in current wd first worked

Answer (score 6):

`apt-cache policy package` displays which versions can be installed from which repositories.

```
bash$ apt-cache policy dpkg
dpkg:
  Installed: 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.1
  Candidate: 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.1 0
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.16.1.2ubuntu7 0
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
apt-get install --yes --no-download --reinstall --print-uris package-name
```

You can extract just URL by adding: `| tail -n1 | grep -o "http[^']\+"`

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. The important part is `--print-uris`

Comment: Doesn't work if the package has unmet deps

Comment: On Debian 11 not works. ```$ sudo apt install --yes --no-download --reinstall --print-uris vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 5):

To get the source:
Check that you have a `deb-src` line in  `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
As root, run `apt-get build-dep package`.
As normal user, run `apt-get source package`.

To get the URL, go to
`http://packages.debian.org/source/sourcepackage`.
Then you get a list of the different versions in the supported archives.
If the source package name differs from the binary, it's in the package description, 2nd line it seems.
`grep -A1 binpackagename /var/lib/apt/*Packages |grep Source` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why nobody suggests `apt show <package-name>`.

Example:

```
$ apt show docker-compose
Package: docker-compose
Version: 1.21.0-3
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Maintainer: Docker Compose Team <team+docker-compose@tracker.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 632 kB
Depends: python3-cached-property (>= 1.2.0), python3-docker (>= 3.2.1), python3-dockerpty (>= 0.4.1), python3-docopt (>= 0.6.1), python3-jsonschema, python3-requests (>= 2.6.1), python3-six (<< 2), python3-six (>= 1.3.0), python3-texttable (>= 0.9.0), python3-websocket (>= 0.32.0), python3-yaml (>= 3.10), python3:any (>= 3.6~), python3-distutils
Recommends: docker.io (>= 1.9.0)
Homepage: http://docs.docker.com/compose/
Download-Size: 108 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Description: Punctual, lightweight development environments using Docker
docker-compose is a service management software built on top of docker. Define
your services and their relationships in a simple YAML file, and let compose
handle the rest.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use website [pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org) where you can search for packages. It will give you package and repository path as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very simple script called `apt-url`, that uses `apt-move` behind the scene to show the package URL.

This script could be found at:

https://github.com/leitao/apt-url